# CodeMirror is not updated source on change

Tags: rascal

I am creating a salix webapp and I am trying to use **codeMirror** as per the salix examples.

I am unable to execute the codeMirror example in the [salix.demo.basic](https://github.com/usethesource/salix/blob/master/src/salix/demo/basic/CodeMirror.rsc), even though I can easily execute all the other examples in basic, so I'm wondering if anything has changed since these were written.

The code I am using:

```
module salix::demo::basic::CodeMirror

import salix::HTML;
import salix::App;
import salix::lib::CodeMirror;
import IO;

alias Model = tuple[list[Msg] changes, str src];

SalixApp[str] cmApp(str id = "root") = makeApp(id, init, view, update, parser=parseMsg);

App[str] cmWebApp()
  = webApp(
      cmApp(), 
      |project://projectName/src/salix/demo/basic/index.html|, 
      |project://projectName/src|
    );


Model init() 
  = <[], "function hello() {\n  console.log(\'Hello world\');\n}">;

data Msg
  = myChange(int, int, int, int, str, str)
  ;

Model update(Msg msg, Model model) {
  switch (msg) {
    case m:myChange(int _, int _, int _, int _, str _, str _):{
      println("Update called");
      model.changes += [m];
    }
  }
  return model;
}

void view(Model model) {
  div(() {
    h2("Code Mirror demo");
    div(() {
      codeMirror("cm", style(("height": "auto")), onChange(myChange), 
        mode("javascript"), lineNumbers(true), \value(model.src));
    });
    for (Msg m <- model.changes) {
      text(m);
      text("; ");
    }
  });
}
```

In my app I have managed to display the codeMirror example as so:

```
codeMirror("cm", onChange(cmChange), style(("height": "50%")),
              lineNumbers(true), \value(model.projectViewInfo.src), lineWrapping(true), class("cm-s-3024-night"));
```

but the change message is never sent (`cmChange`) and the source is never updated. So it is partially working for me.

This example can also be found in the salix library
https://github.com/usethesource/salix/tree/master/src/salix/demo/basic

Comment: Good question. I'll ask a friend.

Comment: Any news? @Jurgen

Comment: @tijs-van-der-storm was asking whether the `basic` demo doesn't execute properly, or only your app. Maybe you can update your question in this regard.

Comment: Whenever i edit the code on the web app I get an error: `jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:9050/root/msg?id=14&maps=&type=codeMirrorChange&fromLine=8&fromCol=2&toLine=8&toCol=2&text=+&removed= 404 (Not Found)`